# Group with order $pq$ has subgroups of order $p$ and $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group with $o(G)=pq$, $p>q$ are primes.

Prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$ and a subgroup of order $q$.

**Remark:** I cannot find the topic with this problem.

I have tried different methods but no one of them did not bring result. Please show how to do that. Do not use Sylow's Theorem.

Comment: Maybe you can use Cauchy's theorem: there is an element of order $p$ and another one of order $q$.

Comment: @Klaramun, In my book (Herstein's book) Cauchy's theorem refers to abelian groups.

Comment: In the abelian case it's easier, but the theorem is general. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Comment: @Klaramun, Yes from Cauchy's theorem we get that there elements of order $p$ and $q$ then it easily follows that there subgroups of order $p$ and $q$, namely cyclic subgroups. Right?

Answer (score 5):

The only way this can fail is if every element other than the identity has
order $p$ or has order $q$. I'll assume order $p$; the other case is similar.

Let $x$ be a non-identity element. Its centraliser $C$ has order
divisible by $p$, so either $C=G$ or $C=\left<x\right>$. In the first
case $\left<x\right>$ is normal in $G$, and as $G/\left<x\right>$
has order $q$, then $y^p$ has order $q$ for any $y\notin\left<x\right>$.

In the second case $x$ has precisely $q$ conjugates. We can assume
this for all $x\ne e$. Then the number of non-identity elements is both a multiple of $q$ and equal to $pq-1$.

Comment: So you mean that my statement is false? Because if all element have order $p$ there is no subgroup of order $q$.

Comment: @RFZ I have shown that this assumption leads to contradiction.

Comment: Regarding second paragraph: why $\langle x \rangle$ has order $q$? It's order is $p$ since order of element $x$ is $p$. And why $y^p$ has order $q$ for $y\notin \langle x \rangle$$